# What use is gold in an outpost in Total War Battles: Kingdom?

Tags: total-war-battles-kingdom

In [Total War Battles: Kingdom](https://twkingdom.com/), when you go to a Viking outpost you're given 30 gold. You can earn gold there, too, from tombs, mines, etc.

But what good is the gold there? I am unable to find anything to spend the gold on.

Note that I'm playing on Android, if that makes a difference, but I don't think that it should.

Comment: [This might interest you](https://blog.twkingdom.com/viking-explorers-update-available-now/)

Comment: @AlfieGoodacre I actually read that, and several other pages, before posting here. Unless I'm missing something, my question is not answered there.

Answer (score 1):

Gold makes a huge difference. For 35 gold, you can change a season for another one. So when you reach winter, you can buy spring instead.
You may find 5 or more gold in tombs.